# Bind keypress event to ListViewItem in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a ListView which populates the view with ListViewItems containing an image and text(file browser). How can I fire a Command when the user presses the 'Enter' key on a selected item while respecting the MVVM design pattern? I've searched and found a few solutions, but none of them seem to work for me.

```
<ListView ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
          VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
          VirtualizingPanel.ScrollUnit="Item"
          Background="#fdfaf4"
          Name="filesView"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">

    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>

            <!-- The image and item name -->
            <Grid Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=filesView, Converter={x:Static converter:GridWidthToListViewWidthConverter.Instance}}" 
                  Background="Transparent">

                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="0.07*" MinWidth="25" MaxWidth="40" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <!-- Drive, file or folder -->
                <Image Grid.Column="0"
                       Margin="0,0,5,0"
                       Name="itemType"
                       Source="{Binding Type,
                       Converter={x:Static converter:HeaderToImageConverter.Instance}}" />

                <!-- The text is binded to the image size, so they'll expand/shrink together -->
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"
                           VerticalAlignment="Center"
                           FontSize="{Binding ActualHeight,
                           ElementName=itemType, Converter={x:Static converter:ImageSizeToFontSizeConverter.Instance}}"
                           Text="{Binding Name}" />

                <!-- The command to enter a drive/folder is called from here -->
                <Grid.InputBindings>
                    <MouseBinding Gesture="LeftDoubleClick" Command="{Binding EnterCommand, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                    <KeyBinding Key="Enter" Command="{Binding EnterCommand, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                </Grid.InputBindings>

            </Grid>

        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>

</ListView>
```

The MouseBinding works just fine. I've tried putting the KeyBinding in the ListView instead of the grid and getting the focused item with the SelectedItem property but still nothing.

Comment: Why exactly the solutions you found didn't work for you? What is your **particular** and **isolated** problem? Any exceptions? Unexpected behavior?

Comment: The problem is that when I press 'Enter', nothing happens. The handler function isn't called.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Implement the `PreviewKeyDown` event for the root `Grid` in the `ItemTemplate` or the `ListViewItem` container in the code-behind of the view and simply execute the command from there, e.g.:

```
private void ListViewItem_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    var viewModel = DataContext as YourViewModel;
    viewModel.YourCommand.Execute(null);
}
```

---

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <EventSetter Event="PreviewKeyDown" Handler="ListViewItem_PreviewKeyDown" />
    </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Or implement a behaviour that hooks up the event handler and does the same: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28959/Introduction-to-Attached-Behaviors-in-WPF.

Neither approach breaks the MVVM pattern since you are invoking the exact same view model command from the exact same view that the XAML markup is a part of.

MVVM is *not* about eliminating code from the views, it is about separation of concerns. If you invoke the command using a `KeyBinding` or an event handler doesn't matter.

Comment: Thanks, looking into it. But so far, it doesn't work if I implement the event for the Grid. It's not called at all, could it be because I'm actually clicking the Image or the TextBlock instead? Could they be on top of the Grid? I'm looking for a workaround

Comment: The Grid needs to be focused. You could handle the PreviewKeyDown event for the ListView itself also.

Comment: If I handle it from the ListView, I get INTERNAL ERROR: Unhandled exception in Debugger::HandleIPCEvent and I can't try-catch this. I think I must handle it from the ListViewItem somehow.

Comment: Hmm...that seems like a debugger error. You shouldn't get an exception if you run without the debugger.

Comment: See my edited answer for an example of how to hook up the event handler for the ListViewItem.

Comment: You're right! But still, I get the ListView as the sender and not the item that is selected. Any idea how can I find which one was focused?

Comment: ListView.SelectedItem?

Comment: Wasn't available. But I did like you said and now it gets called when pressing a button. The only problem is, when I try to assign the DataContext(or the sender) to the item, I get a NullReferenceException. Looks like this and sender are null...

Comment: "Assign DataContext..."? I don't follow. How is this related to your original question of capturing the click event and handle it?

Comment: Sorry, I meant this line: var viewModel = DataContext as YourViewModel;
It says that the viewModel is null

Comment: So your window doesn't have a DataContext? Where is the command that you want to invoke defined then?

Comment: The DataContext is defined in the MainWindow, this is an UserControl. I think that I cannot cast DataContext as the ViewModel I need because it got assigned another type of ViewModel in the MainWindow. Sorry for being so stupid, just got into WPF a week ago

Comment: Yes, that seems to be it. I can't cast the DataContext to my ViewModel.

Comment: It is defined in the ViewModel, but it's not from that. I tried doing
 var viewModel = sender as MyViewModel; and it says that the variable is null. But the sender is not. It looks like the sender is of type ListViewItem and cannot do the cast to my ViewModel

Comment: Found the problem! I needed to do: var viewModel = (sender as ListViewItem).Content as MyViewModel; and then execute the command. Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: @R.Andrei `.Context` not `.Content`?

Answer (score 0):

Try `Gesture="Enter"`;

```
<Grid.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Gesture="Enter" Command="{Binding EnterCommand}" />
</Grid.InputBindings>
```

Comment: Tried, nothing happened... From what I've read, it has to do something with the keyboard not getting focused on the view's items

Comment: There may be other controls that "swallow" certain key combinations. Handle the PreviewKeyDown event as per my suggestion and you should be fine.